# My enemies keep on splicing randomly and I'm not sure why?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, game-development

I'm working on a shooter game where you click to shoot enemies to kill them. There are powerups too, the blue one gives an extra life, and the orange grants immunity. But sometimes, my enemies will randomly get spliced, even though nothing has touched them, as far as I've seen. It gets very noticeable when you get to around 75 points and different types of enemies are spawning in. Then a lot of enemies begin randomly disappearing. I've been thinking a bit, and I only have two conclusions as to why this might be happening. One: I have a lot of code in one file which may be causing performance issues; or two: there is something wrong with my logic. Since I don't know exactly where the problem is stemming from, I am going to put my code in a jsfiddle.net file. Any feedback will be appreciated. Thanks!

https://jsfiddle.net/totallyfarhan/2bcvtmay/3/
Animate Function Code:

```
const animate = () => {
    //gives variable a value each time animate is called
    animationId = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    //clear canvas
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    //canvas background
    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    //bullet foreach iterator
    bullets.forEach((bullet, index) => {
        //allows all bullets to move
        bullet.update()
        //deletes bullets if it moves outside canvas
        if (bullet.x + bullet.radius > canvas.width) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                bullets.splice(index, 1);
            }, 0)
        }

    })
    //enemies foreach iterator
    enemies.forEach((enemy, index) => {
        //allows all enemies to move
        enemy.update()
        //responsible for bullet and enemy collision
        bullets.forEach((bullet, bulletIndex) => {
            //variable used to measure distance between bullet and enemy
            const dist = Math.hypot(bullet.x - enemy.x, bullet.y - enemy.y);
            if (dist - enemy.radius - bullet.radius < 1) {
                //deletes the bullet from bullets array
                bullets.splice(bulletIndex,1)
                //decreases enemy's health
                enemy.health -= 50;
            }
        })
        //enemy dies
        if (enemy.health === 0) {
            //removes enemy from enemies array
            enemies.splice(index, 1)
            //increases score by 1 if regular enemy is killed
            if (enemy.radius === enemyRadius) {
                score ++;
                scoreHTML.innerHTML = score;
            }
            //increases score by 5 if big enemy is killed
            else if (enemy.radius === bigenemyRadius) {
                score += 5;
                scoreHTML.innerHTML = score;
            }
            //increases score by 3 if fast enemy is killed
            else if (enemy.radius === fastenemyRadius) {
                score += 3;
                scoreHTML.innerHTML = score;
            }
        }
        
        //game ends if rocket and enemy collide or no lives remaining
        if (lives === 0) {
            gameOver();
        }
        if (collides(rocket, enemy) && !immunity) {
            gameOver();
        }
        else if (collides(rocket, enemy) && immunity) {
            immunity = false;
            enemies.splice(index, 1);
        }
        //if enemy goes off screen
        if (enemy.x - enemy.radius <= 0) {
            //deletes the enemy from enemies array
            enemies.splice(index, 1);
            //lives go down
            lives --;
            //lives counter is updated
            livesHTML.innerHTML = lives;
        }
    })
    //powerups forEach iterator
    powerups.forEach((powerup, index) => {
        //powerups update function so it can move
        powerup.update();
        //detects rocket and powerup collision
        if (collides(rocket, powerup)) {
            //picks the action for specific powerup
            powerup.pickAction();
            //deletes the powerup from powerups array
            powerups.splice(index, 1);
        }
    })
    //rockets update function so it can move
    rocket.update();
}
```

Comment: I haven't looked through your code yet, but I just wanted to add here that the problem should never be that you have too much code in one file... And having "too much" code in one file should never be inefficient either. (In fact, putting it all in one file technically saves bandwidth, so in a way it's even more efficient.) The issue is almost certainly due to a logic error, and almost certainly not caused by having large amounts of code in a single file. (I can never be certain of course, but I can't think of any way that that could possibly harm anything, so don't worry about it.)

Comment: I can't seem to recreate the problem that you mention here... I played the game about 15 different times and I didn't notice any issues regarding enemies being spliced... (Although I noticed a couple other issues which are unrelated) I couldn't seem to get more than 20 points either, since it takes 3 bullets to kill an enemy and I'm only given 50 bullets... (50 / 3 = ~16) Either I'm missing something here and your question needs more context, or maybe you've changed your code since posting this question... But I'm sorry, I can't help you. I wish you the best!

Comment: Sorry, I'm very late to this, and I definitely forgot to mention a key feature of the game: reloading. To reload, you press 'R,' which gives you 50 bullets again. Sorry for the miscommunication.